# What is the earliest level a warlock can take Hellfire Warlock prestige class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, prestige-class

Hellfire Warlock Requirement is:

> #### Requirements
>
> **Skills:** Intimidate 6 ranks, Knowledge (the planes) 12 ranks, Spellcraft 6 ranks
>
> **Language:** Infernal
>
> **Warlock Invocation:** Must know *brimstone blast* or *hellrime blast*

If I meet these requirements at level 6, can I go into HF warlock prestige class in level 7? I am currently a level 6 warlock however I have 9 skill points invested in Knowledge (the planes) and + 3 is coming from int modifier. Would that make Knowledge(the planes), level 12, or am I capped to level 9 (level + 3 SP) according to PHB?

PHB +3 SP rule:

> If you want to pick up a new skill for your character, you can spend
> skill points equal to his or her character level +3. These skill
> points buy 1 rank each if the new skill is a class skill or 1/2 rank
> each if it’s a cross-class skill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal minimum for 12 ranks in a skill is 9th level. With a bard performing *inspire greatness*, you have two bonus HD, which are included as part of your character level, so when you would otherwise be 7th level, *inspire greatness* can get you to count as character level 9th, and thus allow you to get 12 skill ranks. Normally, this would not matter—you can’t change your skill ranks until you level up, and *inspire greatness* changes your character level, and thus your XP needed to level up. Get around that by having a psion provide *psychic reformation* during the *inspire greatness*—then you can rearrange your skill points immediately.

That’s still only 7th. Getting more ranks after that is somewhat harder—luckily we only need one. There are two options here:

- If the bard performing *inspire greatness* has the Song of the Heart feat from *Eberron Campaign Seeing*, then their *inspire greatness* offers 3 bonus HD, and that solves that problem.
- If a warlock 6th takes *Cityscape*’s Primary Contact as their 6th-level feat, they can get a “bonus rank” in one skill associated with the guild in which they have the Favored feat. This requires, of course, the Favored feat, as well as a guild you can join that’s associated with Knowledge (the planes). *Cityscape* lists several generic types of guilds, and adventurers’ guilds are listed as typically having it, for what it’s worth (and religious guilds can have it and scholastic guilds are even fairly likely to).

With thanks to HeyICanChan for pointing them out, *Yenejg Togan’s planar syllabus* from *Dungeon* vol. 88 and/or the magic volume found among the jackalweres’ treasure in *Expedition to the Demonweb Pits* could be used, as each of these grants a rank of Knowledge (the planes). Many DMs will find the permanent bonuses of Primary Contact, *Yenejg Togan’s planar syllabus*, and the jackalwere’s magical volume more palatable than *inspire greatness* abuse, but it may be extremely challenging for your average 6th-level warlock to obtain loot from an Encounter Level 10 fight from a specific adventure you may not even be playing.

That gets us to 6th, which is the earliest that a warlock can learn *brimstone blast* or *hellrime blast*, the invocations that hellfire warlock requires. That’s just about the best that can be done, because there’s no other way to get those invocations than to be a warlock 6th.

Comment: I am ignoring, for the purposes of this answer, extreme cheese like level drain abuse or manipulate form.

Comment: Where does it say that the bonus Hit Dice from Inspire Greatness count towards your character level?

Comment: @PeregrinTook Character level is equal to your total number of HD, and bonus HD are, ya know, HD. If you want to make some semantic argument that bonus HD aren’t HD, I invite you to do so elsewhere.

Comment: But if the bonus HD are added to the character level and the effective character level now is two levels higher, you also need more XP to attain a new level. So if you start Inspire Greatness before levelling up you don‘t level up at all. Also, if it would work, you would lose the skill ranks as soon as you lose the bonus HD, because _„the maximum number of ranks a character can have in a class skill is equal to his or her character level
+ 3“._

Comment: @PeregrinTook Good point about leveling up, you’re right there. But you’re wrong about the maximum ranks—the rule defining how that limitation works in detail specifies it applies to spending skill points. Once you have the ranks, you have them—there is no mechanism for losing them. Reading *that* into the rules is a bridge too far, I’d think. After all, that would also presumably happen to Primary Contact or *Yenejg Togan’s planar syllabus*, which rather seems to defeat the purpose of those options.

Comment: Also, both Yenejg Togan’s Planar Syllabus, and the unnamed magical volume from EttDP grant ranks, but unlike Primary Contact, they have no exception ruling to allow you to gain ranks over the normal limit. I'd argue Primary Contact is the only choice to enter Hellfire Warlock earlier than normal. And even then you would need a way to acquire that feat at level 8.

Comment: @WannabeWarlock I already acknowledged that. I just have not gotten around to updating the answer. (You still _can_ level up under _inspire greatness_, technically—you just have to get all the XP while continuously under its effect. But that’s beyond absurd unless we use a _thought bottle_, and then that is the kind of extreme cheese I said I was ignoring.) But _inspire greatness_ itself is still viable—we just have to use _psychic reformation_ rather than just level up.

Comment: @YopiLapi Again, no. The skill rank maximum is implemented as a limitation on how you spend skill points. You cannot spend a skill point to increase your rank above the maximum, but if you are already at the maximum, and your rank is increased without involving skill points, then you exceed the maximum. Because they say you get a rank without any reference to your maximum, you get a rank regardless of your maximum. They need to reference it if they want to observe it. And I think this was intentional—it seems to me that only a character knowledgeable of the planes would be interested in these.

Comment: @PeregrinTook Edited to acknowledge that leveling up under _inspire greatness_ isn’t going to work.

Comment: @WannabeWarlock Edited to acknowledge that leveling up under _inspire greatness_ isn’t going to work.

Comment: @KRyan There is no mention at all about skill points in the section where the limitation is detailed: "Ranks indicate how much training or experience your character has with a given skill. Each of his or her skills has a rank, from 0 (for a skill in which your character has no training at all) to a number equal to 3 + character level (for a character who has increased a skill to its maximum rank)." It's "maxium rank", not "maximum rank achievable by spending skill points".

Comment: @YopiLapi The detailed, step-by step breakdown of exactly how leveling works implements the limitation when spending skill points. I read that as an extension/explanation/implementation of what you quote. That is, after all, the section that defines “increas[ing] to [a] rank,” as referenced there. But even if you do not buy that, specific beats general—generally, even if “3 + character level [is] its maximum rank,” these specific items say “you get another rank,” and make no mention of any limitation on that.

Comment: @KRyan I'd rather end this discussion by saying I don't agree. It could be a topic for a separate question.